# iPhone UITableView intercepting cell selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a navigationController with basic data...

When the user selects a cell, I want to highlight the selected cell with a custom background/bold text, etc, and not push the detail view.

When the user touches the already highlighted cell, I would like to push the detail view normally.

So I would like to "intercept" the didSelectRow and let it do something else, before it fires the segue to the detail view.

Comment: What do you mean by "intercept" -- you're writing the code in there. You can make it do whatever you want.

Comment: You will probably have to keep track of the cell state in a custom UITableViewCell. So that in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: you can figure out if the cell was already selected and then push the detail view.

Comment: Rocky is right. You would have to keep some kind of counter, in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, to check if a cell has been tapped twice in a row. Maybe use the dataSource object as a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "intercept", I suppose you're talking about intercepting the segue? To do what you're trying to do, you shouldn't use a segue connected to the cell, instead, you should go to the next controller (with a push or present) in code, so you can trigger it when you want. You would need to keep track of the selected cell, and if it's touched again, then go to the detail view.